# wordpress page that Shows recent comments on the current user's posts

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

in my wordpress website i let registerd users to make posts on the website, now i need to make a page that shows the most recent comments on the posts of the current user.

i have found this code [ref](https://blog.ashfame.com/2011/01/show-recent-comments-particular-user-wordpress/) which shows the comments of the current user not the comments on his posts

```html
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Show Recent Comments by a particular user
Plugin URI: http://blog.ashfame.com/?p=876
Description: Provides a shortcode which you can use to show recent comments by a particular user
Author: Ashfame
Author URI: http://blog.ashfame.com/
License: GPL
Usage: 
*/

add_shortcode ( 'show_recent_comments', 'show_recent_comments_handler' );

function show_recent_comments_handler( $atts, $content = null )
{
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 
        "count" => 10,
        "pretty_permalink" => 0
        ), $atts ));

    $output = ''; // this holds the output
    
    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $args = array(
            'user_id' => $current_user->ID,
            'number' => $count, // how many comments to retrieve
            'status' => 'approve'
            );

        $comments = get_comments( $args );
        if ( $comments )
        {
            $output.= "<ul>\n";
            foreach ( $comments as $c )
            {
            $output.= '<li>';
            if ( $pretty_permalink ) // uses a lot more queries (not recommended)
                $output.= '<a href="'.get_comment_link( $c->comment_ID ).'">';
            else
                $output.= '<a href="'.get_settings('siteurl').'/?p='.$c->comment_post_ID.'#comment-'.$c->comment_ID.'">';         
            $output.= $c->comment_content;
            $output.= '</a>';
            $output.= "</li>\n";
            }
            $output.= '</ul>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output.= "<h2>You should be logged in to see your comments. Make sense?</h2>";
        $output.= '<h2><a href="'.get_settings('siteurl').'/wp-login.php?redirect_to='.get_permalink().'">Login Now &rarr;</a></h2>';
    }
    return $output;
}
?>
```

what can i change in this code to make it gets the comments on the current user posts not his own comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The get_comments function on Wordpress has a whole slew of arguments you can pass through it. To search for comments based on the author of a post, rather than the user_id of the comment, you'll want the "post_author" argument -

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

So, consider changing your $args array accordingly so that it looks for matches where the current_user's ID is the post_author:

```
 $args = array(
        'post_author' => $current_user->ID,
        'number' => $count, // how many comments to retrieve
        'status' => 'approve'
        );
```